# Determine if the CompletedEventArgs returns null (WCF Xamarin VS 2015)

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

The process here is user inputs a number, then the database will select a name that corresponds to the number. If there's no name or if the inputted number doesn't exist, a text will appear on the textview, `Name not found`. The problem is this code probably isn't correct because it isn't showing the `Name not found`, just a blank textview.

```
private void ClientOnDisplayEmployeeCompleted(object sender, DisplayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs)
{
    empName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView9);
    string msg = null;
    if (displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Error != null)
    {
         msg = displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Error.Message;
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetMessage(msg);
         alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {});
         RunOnUiThread(() => { alert.Show(); });
    }
    else if (displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled)
    {
         msg = "Request was cancelled.";
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetMessage(msg);
         alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {});
         RunOnUiThread(() => { alert.Show(); });
    }
    else
    {
         msg = displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Result;
         if (msg == null)
         {
              RunOnUiThread(() => empName.Text = "Name not found");
         }
         else
         {
              RunOnUiThread(() => empName.Text = msg);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of testing for `if (msg == null)` try

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
```

this will handle the case where the value is an empty string or a NULL value

Comment: This gives me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. I moved this `empName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView9);` inside the if else but gets the same error. I changed this `displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Result` to `displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Result.ToString();` but same error. What could be the problem?

Comment: the code I gave you should not throw a null reference error.  You need to use the debugger to figure out which specific line and reference is causing the null exception.

Comment: Just a while ago, it's retrieving the name from the database. I guess your code works but after editing the code, I am getting this: `W/OpenGLRenderer( 4788): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9af17320, error=EGL_SUCCESS`

Comment: Where?  In the console?  Android spits out a lot of console messages that usually don't mean anything.

Comment: Yes, in the debug. The object reference error is from the Android app in emulator.

Comment: Hi, it's finally working again but the `Name not found` still isn't showing up in the textview.

Comment: Hi, I finally managed to make it work by changing it into `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msg)`.